# Avoiding skipped null columns when using terminated and optionally enclosed delimiters

Tags: oracle, null, sql-loader

I regularly upload various tab-delimited text data files with SQL Loader. The control files always specify `TERMINATED BY X'09'`. Certain "cells" in those data files may be null, i.e. there is no character between two subsequent tabs. It always works like a clock.

Now, I have run into a specific case where I have to strip a data column of double quotes that may or may not enclose the actual data (side effect of a text export from Excel).

I tried simply adding `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` behind the terminated delimiter and it did work for the file and column in question. Still, with this new option, files with null values are no longer decoded correctly. The loader seems to simply skip those values, which provokes column shifts and results in either a corrupt load, or a load failure.

For now, I've got a workaround dropping the new option and executing an SQL script eliminating double quotes directly in the database, but that obviously cannot last.

Any ideas?

Comment: To get a decent answer you're going to have to provide some sample data and your control file...

Comment: Do you have `DELIMITED BY X'09'` in your control file?